# 2 unknown grand fathers

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

I have known for a long time that my fathers father is unknown.  Unfortunately, I have learned that my mothers father is unknown also.

I have recently received my DNA results but the nearest match is 3rd to 5th cousins.

Is this an impossible task to find them or is there a strategy to solve both problems?

I m new to DNA and struggling.

Both my parents are irish/scots descent however my DNA returned 10% Baltic/eastern European. My maternal grandfather is believed to be an American or Canadian. I think perhaps that is where the Baltic DNA came from.

Answer (score 1):

you should get second cousins tested if possible, i.e. people that you know relate to ONLY one of your known grandparents.  Your first cousin is no use as they have the same 2 grandparents as you.  Then you can eliminate the 3rd-5th cousins that match this 2nd cousin from your enquiry.

Perhaps you can get older people like your parent(s) tested.  Being 10% Baltic suggests one of your great-grandparents may be 100% Baltic.

You don't say where you tested but another essential strategy is to transfer your DNA everywhere (GEDmatch, FTDNA, MyHeritage) and to get yourself tested on Ancestry (if not already) because that is the biggest pool of matches by a long way.